# react-native: problem when scrolling in horizontal flatlist

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have a horizontal flatlist to render categories the problem is when scrolling the flatlist breaks and get reset as described blow:

[image]

flat list code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <CategorySelector
        category={allCategories}
        isSelected={(selectedCategory === null || allCategories.id === selectedCategory) ? true : false}
      />
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        data={I18nManager.isRTL ? categories.reverse() : categories}
        renderItem={renderCategoryList}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the right FlatList? The code has the scroll indicator turned off, but it's there in the video.

Comment: sorry I turned it on so people can noticed what happened to the flatlist

Answer (score 0):

You can try to provide a getItemLayout value to your Flatlist, see [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout). This will be easy since all your items have the same size. Don't forget the margins.

```
getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
    {length: ITEM_WIDTH, offset: ITEM_WIDTH * index, index}
  )}
```

If it does not help, this might come from the renderItem method. Do you have error messages?

Comment: this is the problem normaly it has to work because it was working before and i didn't change any thing, no there's no errors messages

Comment: I had bugs like this and `getItemLayout` did help; I noticed that it appears especially for long lists. If it's not the case, maybe there is a problem with your data and the `.reverse()` which mutates the array.

Comment: the problem happened before I added the `.reverse()` usually it's working well but when RTL is on, this problem appears